# Is the content of each datafile in the same tablespace the same in Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, database-administration

On Oracle 12c, is the content of each datafile belonging to a single tablespace the same?

If yes, is it because of performance or backup purpose thus recommanding us to store each datafile on different drives?

If no then why would we create multiple datafiles for a single tablespace when we can autoextend each datafile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.
The idea of multiple datafiles supporting a single tablespaces is to be able to use striping. This ofcourse only makes sense if your server has multiple physical storage devices that preferably also have their own io interface.

À table will be in the tablespaces and can allocate space in all available datafiles. So the table data can be in all datafiles.

If your io system does not consist of multiple physical devices you might as well use a bigfile tablespace that just has one big datafile. In older releases this was a restore nightmare because the backup and restore was performed file by file.